# Remember my current view

Tags: ios, uiview

I actually wrote a method which switches some UIViews. When I enter the method I have to know which is my current view to remove exactly this one from the superview. I declared a property for this purpose in the header file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIView *currentView;
```

After I changed to a certain view in my method, I want to assign this view to the property in order to use it when I enter the method again and remove this view from the superview if requested. The method looks like this:

```
...
nextView = [self loadNextView]; // the view is loaded from a NIB here
if (self)
{
    [self viewWillDisappear:YES];
    [[self currentView] removeFromSuperview];
    [[self view] addSubview:nextView];
    [self currentView] = [self nextView];
...
```

Unfortunately the compiler tells me that currentView is not assignable here. Is there another, hopefully better, way to remeber the curernt view for my purpose or should I use a completely different way?

Comment: And please learn C properly, this is something very basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the following line,

```
[self currentView] = [self nextView];
```

do as follows:

```
[self setCurrentView:[self nextView]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign to the value of a function or method call (it returns an rvalue). You have to use the property accessor syntax:

```
self.currentView = [self nextView];
```

or explicitly invoke the setter:

```
[self setCurrentView:[self nextView]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Replace

```
[self currentView] = [self nextView];
```

with

```
self.currentView = [self nextView];
```